# How to represent Unicode codepoints in string literals in Memgraph?

Tags: utf, memgraphdb

What is the correct way to represent Unicode codepoints in string literals in Memgraph? Does memgraph support UTF-16 or UTF-32 codepoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph supports both UTF-16 and UTF-32 codepoints.

You can use `\u` followed by 4 hex digits in string literals for UTF-16 codepoint and `\U` with 8 hex digits for UTF-32 codepoint in Memgraph.